# How to execute class method in order of arguments as given in constructor

Tags: python, oop, python-class

I have created a class, with each of the (keyword-only) arguments in the constructor corresponding to a particular class method. I have also defined another method that executes each of these class methods sequentially. I would like this method to execute the others in **in the order that the corresponding arguments were given in the constructor**, but I'm not sure how I can do this.

My actual code is rather convoluted, so I have provided below a simple but equivalent example of what I mean.

I created the class and defined the methods like so:

```
class thing:
    
    def __init__(self,
                 add_value=1,
                 subtract_value=2,
                 divide_value=3):
        
        self.add_no=add_value
        self.subtract_no=subtract_value
        self.divide_no=divide_value
        
        self.function_list = [
            self.do_addition,
            self.do_subtraction,
            self.do_division]
        
    def do_addition(self, input_no):
        return input_no + self.add_no
        
    def do_subtraction(self, input_no):
        return input_no - self.subtract_no
        
    def do_division(self, input_no):
        return input_no / self.divide_no
        
    def do_thing(self, input_no):
        for i in range(len(self.function_list)):
            function = self.function_list[i]
            output_no = function(input_no)
            input_no = output_no
        return output_no
```

If I then initialize a class object:

```
my_thing = thing(add_value=3,
                 subtract_value=1,
                 divide_value=2)
```

And run the `do_thing` method:

```
my_thing.do_thing(10)
```

The output is `6.0`, as expected. Of course, the output will depend on the order in which the `do_addition`, `do_subtraction`, and `do_division` methods are executed. I'm wondering if there is a way of executing these methods in the order given in the constructor, such that the following would return `7.5` (instead of `6.0`):

```
my_thing_2 = thing(subtract_value=1,
                   divide_value=2,
                   add_value=3)
```

I'm quite new to classes in Python so I would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a workaround which meets the intentions of the question, even though it's not, strictly speaking, an answer.

This involves adding an `order` argument to the final method `do_thing` (which is renamed `calculate` in the code below), which lets the user specify the order of operations for the class methods.

The constructor creates the `function_list` attribute automatically and orders the functions within it alphabetically.

```
class thing:
    
    def __init__(self,
                 add_value=None,
                 subtract_value=None,
                 divide_value=None):
        
        self.add_no=add_value
        self.subtract_no=subtract_value
        self.divide_no=divide_value
        
        function_names = sorted([f for f in dir(self) 
                               if callable(getattr(self, f)) 
                               and f.startswith("do_")],
                              key=lambda f: f.lower())
        self.function_list = [getattr(self, i) for i in function_names]

    def do_addition(self, input_no):
        if self.add_no is not None:
            return input_no + self.add_no
        else:
            return input_no
        
    def do_subtraction(self, input_no):
        if self.add_no is not None:        
            return input_no - self.subtract_no
        else:
            return input_no
            
    def do_division(self, input_no):
        if self.add_no is not None:        
            return input_no / self.divide_no
        else:
            return input_no
            
    def calculate(self, input_no, order=None):
        if order:
            op_order = order
        else:
            op_order =range(len(self.function_list))
        for i in op_order:
            function = self.function_list[i]
            output_no = function(input_no)
            input_no = output_no
        return output_no
```

This at least gives a specific order which can then be altered using the `order` argument in `calculate`. So initializing the class object as before:

```
my_thing = thing(add_value=3,
                 subtract_value=1,
                 divide_value=2)
```

We get an object that orders the methods like so: (0)`do_addition` `->` (1)`do_division` `->` (2)`do_subtraction`, and we can alter this order by passing the argument in `calculate` like so:

```
my_thing.calculate(10,order=[2,1,0])
```

Which returns `7.5`, as desired.

Again, because the order is not given by the actual order of the kwargs in the constructor upon initialization, this is not an answer to my question. It is, however, a way to get the desired results, so I'm posting it here for future reference!